# SSH doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-access, openssh

I am trying to connect to my webserver via ssh but I can't. When I insert the password nothing happens. This is what I see:

```
# ssh username@username.example.com
username@username.example.com's password:
```

Why? In iptables there are no rules. Please help :(

I have tried with a wifi connection of my friend and it does work!!
So is it a router problem?

What I have to do?

Comment: works for me.  can you try again using one of the debugging options (`-v` or `-vv` or `-vvv`) and post the result?  also, which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Well. Try using the simple "ssh machine1.something.com" method, and also, you won't see your password inserted. Just type it blindly and hit enter. At least an error should come up.

Comment: yes this is what I see: http://pastebin.com/2sWHMHSW
I am using ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: I dont see any problem with it ^^". Try the -vvv. Maybe we'll see more.

Comment: ok this is it: http://pastebin.com/HqqMJJGX

Thanks :)

Comment: Does it work with Windows+Putty? (The connection). If yes, try launching ssh from 'xterm'.

Comment: I don't have windows.
from xterm I get the same problem :(. What I have to do ?

Comment: I just tested `ssh -vvv` and got similar output, but then a little more. This shows the end of the sequence. The highlighted lines are the lines after the end of what xrobot shows http://pastebin.com/0U9VrR93

Comment: with wifi connection of my friend, I can connect via ssh but with my LAN no !!
Maybe is a router issue ?

Comment: Did you compare the output of `ssh -vvv` on your friend's wifi connection vs what you see on your LAN?

Comment: What does /var/log/auth.log say?

Comment: It is also possible that your web server is doing strict reverse DNS checking, and the IP address where you're having problems is not registered correctly in DNS.

Comment: Maybe my ISP is blocking port 22 ?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with your router or your ISP. Look at line 7 of your pastebin entry -- it says "Connection established."

Comment: I have just installed putty and works !! boh :-\

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried pushing enter after typing your password? The password does not show up when you use SSH...

Comment: yes I have pushed enter many times but doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: I see you are troubleshooting in the comments above. Disregard my answer.